# How to upgrade my Zen sub-theme so that navigation and most of the blocks are no longer missing?

Tags: theming

I have been looking quite a bit for a "step by step" for what people did to upgrade their Zen Sub-themes from its 6.x version to the 7.x-5.x version.

I did not make the sub theme I'm working with and I am not familiar with the process (last webmaster made it).

The issue I am having: the front page and all other pages don't have navigation and almost all the blocks are missing.

In my searching I saw that the `.info` file and `template.php` file have something that needs to be done. Haven't been able to really get a good outcome at all.

This is how my 6.x regions look like:

```
regions[sidebar_first]  = First sidebar
regions[sidebar_second] = Second sidebar
regions[navigation]     = Navigation bar
regions[highlight]      = Highlighted content
regions[content_top]    = Content top
regions[content_bottom] = Content bottom
regions[header]         = Header
regions[footer]         = Footer
regions[page_closure]   = Page closure

regions[footer_col1]   = Footer Column 1
regions[footer_col2]   = Footer Column 2
regions[footer_col3]   = Footer Column 3
regions[footer_col4]   = Footer Column 4

regions[homepage_col1]   = Homepage Column 1
regions[homepage_col2]   = Homepage Column 2
regions[homepage_col3]   = Homepage Column 3
```

Any suggestions about how I should proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. You need to provide more detailed information in order to get some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue about [How to upgrade Zen theme from 6.2 to 7.3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1165028) contains quite some info (and links to other resources) about such Zen upgrade. However it also includes these suggestions about possible alternatives to consider:

- Something like "maybe you should just consider restarting from scratch".
- Swap from the [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) theme to the [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) theme (by creating an Omega sub-theme from scratch).

For more in depth documentation, you might want to look at [Upgrading 6.x themes to 7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/254940).

Based on the current (further edited) content of your question, these are some of the topics to be sorted out (at least):

1. ### Navigation:

   The navigation items shown in D6, possibly correspond to your primary and/or secundary menus (though they may also come from some "custom" menu that got added). Check which technique was used to actually display that menu in D6. Possible options I can think of: (a) some block makes them show up or (b) some theme settings is turned on (enabled checkbox) to make them display. Depending on which option was used, try to find the corresponding D7 options to do the same there.
2. ### Blocks:

   For any of the blocks shown in the D6 version, in which theme region were they displayed? Head over to the D7 version to verify where probably "most of these blocks" will be shown within the "disabled" list of blocks. For any such block you find, in the D7 version start experimenting with moving those disabled blocks to what you think will be the most appropriate region in D7.

   Keep repeating this for each of your blocks that are missing (= iterative process). In doing so, little by little most (if not all) of your blocks should start showing up).

If sorting out the above topics appears to be too complicated and/or turns out to take too long, then I'd really consider going the route of either possible alternatives mentioned above, because creating a "sub-theme" from the most recent Zen or Omega theme might simplify further maintenance of your "custom" theme also.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still experiencing issues :/
Could I forward you a link with some files?

Comment: So reading through the upgrade links it said the .info page needed to be changed, as well as the template.php and some files that had .tpl.php so my question is A) how they correspond, and B) how many things need to be changed when one thing is changed? For instance, when I change "content_top" and "content_bottom" to just "content" how to I make that effect all the other pages? Thank you again for your assistance